# JavaScript find() method searches through an array of objects to find an element, the outcome not accessible

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, find, javascript-objects

```
 //array of objects
 const posts = [ {userId: 1, id: 1, title: "sunt", author: 
 "Tom"},
 {userId: 1, id: 2, title: "qui est esse",author: "Tom"},
 {userId: 1, id: 3, title: "ea molestias", author: "Tom"}, 
 {userId: 1, id: 4, title: "eum et est occaecati", author: 
 "Tom"}]

 //id of one of the object
 const ItemId = 2

 //trying to find the object that has id: 2 an then print other 
 key -values pairs from that prticular object

 let post= posts.find(item=> item.id===ItemId)
 console.log(post)
 //result: {userId: 1, id: 2, title: "qui est esse",author: 
 "Tom"}
 console.log(post.title)
 //result: undefined --- why can not access these properties?
 console.log(post.author)
 //result: undefined
 console.log (typeof post)
 //result:  "string" --- why string, its an object is it?
```

Appreciate any insights, I dont follow why those find() method results can not be access by the way we access propreties in objects? I have also tried using brackets like this: post[author) with no success... Thanks a lot for anything on the subject

Comment: Could you look through your code, some of it is not valid javascrript. And when correcting those problems i do not get any problems.

Comment: `const ItemId: 2` an example of the invalid syntax

Answer (score 1):

Don't you get any errors? because when I copied your code and run then it has multiple errors.

```
//array of objects
const posts = [ {userId: 1, id: 1, title: "sunt", author: "Tom"},
{userId: 1, id: 2, title: "qui est esse",author: "Tom"},
{userId: 1, id: 3, title: "ea molestias", author: "Tom"}, 
{userId: 1, id: 4, title: "eum et est occaecati", author: 
"Tom"}];
let post= posts.find(item=> item.id===2)
console.log(post)
console.log(post.title)
console.log(post.author)
console.log (typeof post)
```

Try this code. Its is returning everything correct

Answer (score 1):

Your code seem to have a couple of syntax errors:

First you forgot to put a comma after one of the elements in the array. Each element should be separated by a comma `{userId: 1, id: 2, title: "qui est esse",author: "Tom"},`

A local variable in Javascript can be set a value using a `=` sign. In your code you were using `const ItemId: 2`. Declaring a variable using `:` should only be used when declaring it inside an Object, but not when declaring a local variable or constant.

This is the full code with the fixed syntactical errors:

```
 //array of objects
 const posts = [ {userId: 1, id: 1, title: "sunt", author: 
 "Tom"},
 {userId: 1, id: 2, title: "qui est esse",author: "Tom"},
 {userId: 1, id: 3, title: "ea molestias", author: "Tom"}, 
 {userId: 1, id: 4, title: "eum et est occaecati", author: 
 "Tom"}];

 //id of one of the object
 const ItemId = 2;

 //trying to find the object that has id: 2 an then print other  key -values pairs from that prticular object

 let post= posts.find(item=> item.id===ItemId)
 console.log(post)
 //result: {userId: 1, id: 2, title: "qui est esse",author: "Tom"}
 console.log(post.title)
 //result: undefined --- why can not access these properties?
 console.log(post.author)
 //result: undefined
 console.log (typeof post)
 //result:  "string" --- why string, its an object is it?
```

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks ive corrected that, but issue remains. when i run this code in Repl.it and it work fine, those four console.log produce correct result. But when i run VStudio and the through Chrome console it dosent work, i get 3 undefined and typeof as string, hmmm?

Comment: @TomSpatula If the errors still persist then it should be outside this block of code. I cannot test the rest of the code.

Comment: "i get 3 undefined and typeof as string" but you @TomSpatula dont mention this anywhere in your original question nor state the *actual* and *full* error message? Why? Why be hiding and now summarizing errors that are crucial to debugging? ... This isnt a hide and seek game I hope.